# js display of uint256 is not correct?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, javascript

I have a simple contract to set and get a uint256 variable:

```
contract testContract {

   uint256 test;

   function testContract() {    
   }

   function getTest() constant returns (uint256) {
       return test;    
   }

   function setTest(uint256 _test) {
       test = _test;    
   } 
}
```

On geth, I update the `test` variable by

```
myContract.setTest.sendTransaction(0x12345678901234567890,{from: web3.eth.accounts[0]});
```

Now to read the variable by

```
var cardPK = myContract.getTest.call();
console.log("test: " + cardPK.toString(16));
```

And I obtained

```
test: 12345678901233c56f80
```

Why is it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to send a big number to contract is by doing :

```
myContract.setTest.sendTransaction(web3.toBigNumber('0x12345678901234567890'),{from: web3.eth.accounts[0]});
```